# Duplicate identifier 'export='

Tags: typescript

I know this question was asked here before, but none of the solutions is working for me. I have the following tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/*"],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

but when I run `tsc` I get:

```
../node_modules/@types/passport/index.d.ts(100,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
node_modules/@types/passport/index.d.ts(100,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

How is it possible that I still get `../node_modules/@types/ (etc)` when I specifically said only include the `./src` folder and only types from `./node_modules/@types`?

I'm using typescript Version 2.4.0 (but have the same problem with version 2.3.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you try the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "declaration": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. The "skipDefaultLibCheck" wasn't needed and is flagged deprecated. Can you elaborate a bit what was the problem before and how you came to this solution?

Comment: I haven't reproduced your problem so it's hard for me to be specific. There's no need to specify the `typeRoots` if it's the default `node_modules/@types` dir ([check this for more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)). Also, `skipLibCheck` will cause the compiler to ignore checking the libraries you are using and so you won't get errors from used libs. You're welcome to play around with these options and see what actually fixed it.